# Codeigniter fetching data error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I'm fetching a data from database using CI. Whenever I output the result, I always get an error and a null value. The error is :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: user/joinroomlanding.php
Line Number: 31
```

Output the page controller:

```
public function joinroom(){
    $data['title'] = "User| Join Room";
    $data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
    $data['room'] = $this->user_model->joinRoom();

    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == 2 ){
        $this->load->view('include/header_user',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/navbar_user');
        $this->load->view('user/joinroomlanding');
        $this->load->view('include/footer_user');
    } else {
        redirect('restricted');
    }
}
```

Validation of the input:

```
public function joinRoomValidation(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('roomCode', 'Room Code', 'required|xss_clean|numeric');


    if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
        if($this->user_model->joinRoom() == true){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p class='alert alert-success'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true'></span> Room found successfully.</p>");
            redirect('joinroomlanding');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p class='alert alert-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span> You need to enter a valid room code.</p>");
            redirect('user_roomlist');
        }
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p class='alert alert-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign' aria-hidden='true'></span> You need to enter a room code.</p>");
        redirect('user_roomlist');
    }
}
```

Model :

```
public function joinRoom(){
    $roomCode = $this->input->post('roomCode');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('room_code', $roomCode);
    $query =  $this->db->get('room');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

joinroomlanding.php

```
 <div class="text-center"><?php echo $message;?></div>
     <div class="panel panel-green">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="text-center">
             <h3><?php echo $room->room_name; ?></h3>
             <h3><?php var_dump($room->room_name); ?></h3>
             <h3><?php echo $room->room_code; ?></h3>
             <h3><?php echo $room->date_created; ?></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Native php query solve this answer(joinroomlanding.php) :

```
$classCode=$this->input->post('classCode');
$sql= "SELECT * FROM class WHERE class_code='".$classCode."'";
$result= mysql_query($sql); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['class_name'];
echo $row['class_section'];
echo $row['class_description'];
echo $row['class_limit'];
}
```

Comment: can you show where Line 31 (from the error) would be in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is happening because your model is returning your results using: `row_array()`, which means your results are in array format, meaning you would need to obtain them using `[]` like `$result['room_name']`, however, when you are iterating these results in your view, you are assuming these results are in object form, thus doing this: `<?php echo $room->room_name; ?>  ...`

In order to fix it, change your model return method from this:

```
...
if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return $query->row_array();
} else {
...
```

to this:

```
...
if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return $query->row();
} else {
...
```

Source: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE:**

To convert this into Codeigniter:

```
$classCode=$this->input->post('classCode');
$sql= "SELECT * FROM class WHERE class_code='".$classCode."'";
$result= mysql_query($sql); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['class_name'];
 echo $row['class_section'];
 echo $row['class_description'];
 echo $row['class_limit'];
}
```

Do the following: break down what belongs in your model, controller and view:

**Model:**

```
function model_method($classCode){
    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('class');
    $this->db->where('class_code', $classCode);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result_array();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function controller_method(){
    $classCode = $this->input->post('classCode');
    $this->load->model('model_name');
    $data['result'] = $this->model_name->model_method($classCode);
    $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
echo $result['class_name'];
echo $result['class_section'];
echo $result['class_description'];
echo $result['class_limit'];
```

Comment: actually someone already mention that answer `return $query->row();` it returns a boolean false.

Comment: Well then that means you are either getting 0 results or more than 1. You need to run tests on your results then based on thay fix your conditionals

Comment: my friend solve it with this query ill edit it can you help me to transfer it in codeigniter?

Comment: yeah i can help you. What do you need exactly?